# Show Fade Item as long as cursor is hover it

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".Button").hover(function(){
      $(".FadeItem").fadeIn("slow");
     },
     function(){
        $(".FadeItem").fadeOut();
     });
    });
```

```css
     .FadeItem{
    display: none;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


       <div class="Button">Button</div>
    
     <div class="FadeItem">
     
      <ul>     
      <li>1.1. Menu </li>
      <li>1.2. Menu</li>
      </ul>
      
     </div>
```

As you can see the simple code above fades in the content of the two list items. The fadein of those two items works perfectly. However, I want that those items stay visible as long as the cursor is on them. Once the cursor goes out they should disappear.

Do you have any idea what I need to change in my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed your HTML a bit and it works great. Move the `ul` part to inside  div which have button text. So when you move out of the whole div, then only it gets invisible.

https://jsfiddle.net/sureshatta/2f21u2qx/3/

```js
$(".Button").hover(function(){
  $(".FadeItem").fadeIn("slow");
 },
 function(){
    $(".FadeItem").fadeOut();
 });
```

```css
.FadeItem {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Button">Button
  <div class="FadeItem">
    <ul>     
      <li>1.1. Menu</li>
      <li>1.2. Menu</li>
    </ul>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you will add ul also on hover it will works.

$(document).ready(function () {
$(".Button, ul").hover(function(){
    $(".FadeItem").fadeIn("slow");
},
function(){
$(".FadeItem").fadeOut();
 });
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Button">Button
 <div class="FadeItem">

    <ul>                    
    <li>1.1. Menu </li>
    <li>1.2. Menu</li>
    </ul>

 </div> 
</div

.FadeItem {
 display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your `.fadeItem` block inside your `.Button`.

```js
$(".Button").hover(function(){
 $(".FadeItem").fadeIn("slow");
},
function(){
    $(".FadeItem").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.FadeItem{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Button">Button
  <div class="FadeItem">
 
  <ul>     
  <li>1.1. Menu </li>
  <li>1.2. Menu</li>
  </ul>
  
 </div> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Button").hover(function () {
        $(".FadeItem").fadeIn("slow");
    },
    function () {
        $(".FadeItem").hover(function () {
            $(".FadeItem").fadeIn("slow");
        },
         function () {
             $(".FadeItem").fadeOut();
         },
           function () {
               $(".FadeItem").fadeOut();
           })
    });


});
```

```css
.FadeItem{
    display: none;
     }
     
Button:hover,.FadeItem:hover{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


       <div class="Button">Button</div>
    
     <div class="FadeItem">
     
      <ul>     
      <li>1.1. Menu </li>
      <li>1.2. Menu</li>
      </ul>
      
     </div>
```

try this one.